# Hide Unsupported Matter Endpoints in Google Home

Tags: google-smart-home

I am working on a Matter device that includes a dimmer (type 0x0104) endpoint (lets call that Endpoint EP1) as well as several Generic Switch (type 0x000F) endpoints (lets call them EP2, EP3, EP4). The Generic Switch endpoints support button tapping for 3 different buttons (each allowing press, hold, double tap) on Apple iOS Home, but are not supported in Google Home and create icons that are basically functionless.

I'm wondering - is there a way to build and provision something like a "driver" in Google Home so that, when the device is commissioned by a end-user, Google Home knows that endpoints EP2, EP3, EP4 should be hidden?

I'm thinking this might be possible through the developer console: https://developers.home.google.com/matter/project/create, which indicates you can upload your device certificates, product / vendor ID and set up configurations for the device -- can anybody confirm - does this console allow setting up a configuration as I've suggested?

If so, are there further instructions on this (I can't seem to find something that more precisely confirms what I'm looking for).
Thanks.

Tried reviewing the Google Home documentation but couldn't find clear answer.

Comment: As of now, Google Home and the associated Matter ecosystem do not offer a direct mechanism for device manufacturers or developers to define custom configurations, such as hiding specific endpoints, through the developer console.